Help Identify Component(s)
I'm trying to recreate this circuit.  It is a device that plugs into another device that sends a servo a quarter turn in one direction or the other with a single push of this button. I'm assuming the device in the middle is performing the latching.
This push button toggle circuit is either 0V or +5V on the signal.  I'm trying to identify the two circled components. The top left (yellow circle) is likely an SMD capacitor and the lower center (red circle) is likely a Zener diode.  The IC is a Z14 and is a dual inverter Schmitt trigger.  I'm guessing these components are being used as a hardware button debouncing.  Another more difficult question I have is why a Zener diode?


Please show image of other side of the PCB.

design one from scratch

It wouldn't make much sense for that diode to be a zener, unless there's something strange going on.
